# Timer.publish() vs Timer(fire:...)

Tags: swift, timer, combine

I need a one-second timer in my app, ideally firing on or just after the integral wall-clock second. Traditionally I would do this using `Timer(fire date: Date,…)` and pre-compute the appropriate `Date` for the upcoming second. I do this to ensure second-resolution timers in my app are well-synced to wall clock time, as one second is a long time, even for a human, in this app.

Is there any way to set up a first-fire date using `Timer.publish()`? Aside from using a regular timer to set it up, that is.

Comment: This seems like a bad use of a Timer to start with. They are not accurate enough. I would suggest using a display link instead, and just look at the clock to see if we just crossed an integral seconds boundary. If so, take action (could fire off a PassthroughSubject if using Combine). If not, do nothing.

Comment: Plenty accurate, just has to be "soon" after the integral boundary (e.g. < 100 ms).